# MongoDB find items with distinct field

Tags: mongodb

I want to get specific entries in my collection according to the following schema.

It musst be the same `objectClass` sorted by the `version` to get the newest and filtered then to get only the latest by `objectId`(note: that is not the item id!!!)

I already tried some combinations with distinct and group but dont get it

**Collection(history):**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("AAA"), "objectId" : ObjectId("BBB"), "objectClass" : "AAA\BBB\CCC", "version" : NumberInt("1"), "fields" : {...} }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("AAB"), "objectId" : ObjectId("BBB"), "objectClass" : "AAA\BBB\CCC", "version" : NumberInt("2"), "fields" : {...} }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("AAC"), "objectId" : ObjectId("BBB"), "objectClass" : "AAA\BBB\CCC", "version" : NumberInt("3"), "fields" : {...} }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("AAD"), "objectId" : ObjectId("BBA"), "objectClass" : "AAA\BBB\CCC", "version" : NumberInt("1"), "fields" : {...} }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("AAE"), "objectId" : ObjectId("BBA"), "objectClass" : "AAA\BBB\CCC", "version" : NumberInt("2"), "fields" : {...} }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("AAF"), "objectId" : ObjectId("BBA"), "objectClass" : "AAA\BBB\CCC", "version" : NumberInt("3"), "fields" : {...} }
```

**My current statement (returns not expected result):**

```
db.history.find({objectClass: "AAA\BBB\CCC"}).sort({version: -1});
```

**Expected result:**

```
[
    { "_id" : ObjectId("AAC"), "objectId" : ObjectId("BBB"), "objectClass" : "AAA\BBB\CCC", "version" : NumberInt("3"), "fields" : {...} }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("AAF"), "objectId" : ObjectId("BBA"), "objectClass" : "AAA\BBB\CCC", "version" : NumberInt("3"), "fields" : {...} }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use an aggregate and pipe in a few calls. Below is a query I didn't test but should give you a good idea. Sort the documents first, then group by the objectClass and get only the first value for the other fields, finally project the data back to its original format.

```
db.history.aggregate([
    {
        "$match":{ "objectClass": "AAA\BBB\CCC" }
    },{
        "$sort": {"version":-1} 
    },{
        "$group":{
            "_id":"$objectId",
            "objectClass": {"$first": "$objectClass"},
            "version": {"$first": "$version"},
            "origId": {"$first": "$_id"},
            "fields": {"$first": "$fields"}
        }
    },{
        "$project":{
            "_id":"$origId",
            "objectId": "$_id",
            "objectClass":1,
            "version": 1,
            "fields": 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: you missed a `}`, and `$mach` but work awesome! thank you! +1

Comment: @JasonSchilling Thanks for pointing out what I missed. I went back and fixed the query